# How to extract only a specific folder from a zipped archive to a given directory?

Tags: zip

How does one extract a specific folder from a zipped archive to a given directory?

I tried using

```bash
unzip "/path/to/archive.zip" "in/archive/folder/" -d "/path/to/unzip/to"
```

but that only creates the folder on the path I want it to unzip to and does nothing else.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```bash
unzip /path/to/archive.zip "in/archive/folder/*" -d "/path/to/unzip/to"
```

Comment: If you get 'caution: filename not matched: '/dir1/dir2/*' when you try to extract something like '/dir1/dir2/*' - remove first '/' from the path, so it becomes 'dir1/dir2/*'. Double-check the existence of the path if this won't work.

Answer (score 47):

Try:

```bash
unzip /path/to/archive.zip 'in/archive/folder/*' -d /path/to/unzip/to
```

Comment: did this? I get `caution: filename not matched: foldername/\*` when I run `unzip $repozip "$2-master/\*" -d /srv/www/magento/` where `$2` is the folder name in the zip I want to pull all the files and folders out of

Comment: Then the filename was not matched.  Do `unzip -l xxx.zip` to see what's in `xxx.zip`.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work for me either!

Comment: Worked without \, just `"path/*"`.

Comment: Is there a way to extract contents of "in/archive/folder/*" that does not preserve path "in/archive/folder/"?  I end up using `mv` afterwards to get files where I needed them.

Comment: Use `-j` for that.

Comment: `-j` strips all path info, and all files go into the target folder.  Is there a way to remove only the common part of the path?  Akin to zip `-r`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "akin to zip -r".  If you're asking for a way to strip some of the path elements, but not all of the path elements in the names stored in the zip file, then no, unzip does not have a means to do that.

Comment: the double quotation for the `in/archive/folder` didn't work for me. @sue's single quotation solution worked find for me

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone I need to do this to fill an existing directory structure with some files from the ZIP file.  What I've done is just unzip naively, giving me the directory structure I don't want, but then do `rsync -a path/i/dont/want/dir/ path/i/do/want/dir`, then delete the unwanted directory.  Note that the trailing slash on the first and the lack of trailing slash on the second are important for rsync.

Answer (score 8):

The existing two answers are both correct, but it's a bit tricky to specify the target directory, that should be better clarified.

Let's say `/target/root/` is the target dir upon the original unzip action, e.g.:

```bash
unzip -qq src.zip -d "/target/root/"
```

Then, we need to use the same `/target/root/` as the target dir afterward even though we want to extract only a specific sub-directory, as the way unzip works:

```bash
unzip -qq src.zip "sub/dir/*" "/target/root/"
```

After all, the rule is actually simple, **use the same target root directory for the `-d` option**.

BTW, the `-qq` option is for unzip to be really quiet, feel free to remove it.

Comment: FYI: I did <kbd>unzip -qq 2.3.zip "magento2-2.3/vendor/*" "vendor/"</kbd> and got
<kbd>caution: filename not matched:  vendor/`</kbd>. This is on an ubuntu install in bash. I rarely unzip, probably did something else wrong...

Comment: For me this unzipped the files in that specific directory, but did not pick up subdirectories; is that a different command?

Comment: The first time I read this I couldn’t make any sense of it at all.  Then I read it a second time and I thought I understood it.  Then I read it a third time and got a different meaning.  Your answer should be [better] clarified. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Also, you refer to “the original unzip action”.  What makes you think that there *was* a previous unzip action?  What if I want to look at data for April 2017, so I download `2017.zip` from the server and I want to extract the `April` folder (and nothing else)?

Answer (score 4):

To extract subfolders as well within the desired one use `**/*` wildcard:

```bsh
unzip src.zip 'path/in/archive/**/*' -d /target/dir/
```

It is important to put the pattern into single quotes, to prevent the shell from interpreting and expand the wildcard characters.

Tested on `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.`

Comment: for the people who don't want to think, just get it done, this is the answer

Comment: **-1: Misinfo.** 1. No, you don't need `folder/**/*` to "extract subfolders within the desired folder". `folder/*` already extracts the whole folder and all subfiles and all subfolders and all files within all subfolders. The whole tree is extracted. 2. You don't need single quotes. The shell never expands asterisks inside any quotes at all, whether they are double or single. 3. I am using the exact same version of UnZip. So what I just said is the same for you too.

Comment: @Mitch McMabers Please have a look at my answer to know why this is not misinformation - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/748349/356166

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify both `*` and `**/*` for every `path/in/archive/`

```bash
unzip src.zip 'path/*' 'path/**/*' -d /target/dir/
```

this works.

Omitting either one, skips any files present.

Example:

```bash
unzip aar.aar 'res/**/*' 'res/*' -d /lib/res/
```

Comment: This worked as expected, it unzips files AND directories stored in the specified folder inside the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

To continue on @Z4- and @scriptmaster answer.

I tested unzip on all three OS -

- Linux (Ubuntu 23.04)
- macOS (Ventura 13.4)
- Windows 11 (Git BASH 2.41.0.windows.1)

All the OS had the following version -

```
unzip --help
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.
```

On Ubuntu and macOS, the following command was sufficient to extract a specific folder with all its contents including subfolders and its contents.

```bash
unzip src.zip 'path/*' -d /target/dir/
```

But on Git for Windows, the following command is required.

```bash
unzip src.zip 'path/*' 'path/**/*' -d /target/dir/
```

So the best way would be to extract all files to some temp directory and then move to the target directory

```
unzip src.zip -d /temp/dir/
mv /temp/dir/path /target/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in MacOS (arm) but the following works perfectly:

```
unzip <*.zip> -d <my_folder>
```