# extract only a specific folder Contents from a zipped archive to a given directory

Tags: bash, zip

This is very close to the SO [How to extract only a specific folder from a zipped archive to a given directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59276/how-to-extract-only-a-specific-folder-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory/59285#comment146490_59285)  I need something close but I always get the folder with the contents, not it's contents only  This is what was suggested:

```
 #note $2 is passed in and would be == "magefoler"
 unzip /srv/file.zip "$2-master/*" -d /srv/www/mage/
```

What I need to do it to take a zip that has this structure in it

```
file.zip
 |-magefoler-master/
 |-magefoler-master/app/*tons of files
 |-magefoler-master/skin/*tons of files
```

and I need to move it to another folder but, I can't move the `magefoler`, I only want the `app` and `skin` folders.  This doesn't mean that it'll always be those two folders, just that any child content, files or folders, in the `magefoler` is what I need to get out.  What is trying to be avoided is to export all to a folder and then just move it from there.

The end result I'm looking for is from the zip file I output to the `/mage` folder like this:

```
/srv/www/mage/
     |--/mage/app/*tons of files
     |--/mage/skin/*tons of files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just unzip to here:

```
$ unzip /srv/file.zip "$2-master/*" -d /srv/www/
```

And then move/rename the folder `magefoler-master` to `mage`:

```
$ mv /srv/www/magefoler-master /srv/www/mage
```

#### Alternatives?

In researching this exact problem in the past I was only able to find 2 additional methods to doing something like this without having to resort to using the `mv`.

1. Using FUSE as Gilles suggests here: [How can I force unzip / zip not to create a subdirectory when I extract it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38162/how-can-i-force-unzip-zip-not-to-create-a-subdirectory-when-i-extract-it)
2. Using the tool `zipnote` to move the files within the zip archive, prior to extracting them out.

Comment: well no mage is a folder with things in it, and that approach of unzip then move contents out is what I'm trying to avoid.  It's an extra I/O step and takes time that is sorely needed to be saved.  The deal is I have about 30 of these and it's on a VM to a shared folder so it's slow so trying to skip the just dump and move contents is the goal

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - I'm not sure what you're saying here. Moving a folder only requires one change, the inode that represents the folder has to just have its name changed, nothing more, no files need to actually move in this operation.

Comment: even thou there is files and folders (many with the same names) in the `mage` folder, it will not file by file move the whole thing? seems like there would be a lot of I/O here.. ?

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - no the files in the folder don't need to move with this operation. As long as the folder remains on the same physical disk then it's literally no overhead to perform this type of move. It's really a rename more than a move.

Comment: well I guess I'll give that a go, seems odd that I can't just get the contents of a folder.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC - I'd tend to agree with you but in looking through this in the past I could find no method beyond this and 2 others: (1) Using FUSE as Gilles suggests here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38162/how-can-i-force-unzip-zip-not-to-create-a-subdirectory-when-i-extract-it and (2) Using the tool `zipnote` to move the files within the zip archive, prior to extracting them out.